# Link piece of html text with ruby variables to html file

Tags: html, ruby

I have a piece of html text that includes some ruby variables, and depends on a loop with unknown number of iterations. What I have now (and works):

**test.rb** (piece)

```
head = <<-HEAD
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
  HEAD

body = '<div class="flex-container">'

items.each do |i|
  body << %(
    <div class="container">
      <button id='action#{i.ref}'
        style="background-color: 'inherit';"
        onmouseover="this.id='action'; this.style.background='highlight';"
        onclick="selectItem()"
        onmouseout="this.id='action#{i.ref}'; this.style.background='inherit';"
        value="#{i.root}">
      <img src="#{i.image}" alt="#{i.name}_img">
      <div>#{i.name}</div>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
end

body += '</div></body></html>'
html = head + body
```

That is the way I generate my html text. I want to have a separate html file and somehow link what's in the body to the ruby code of last example, i.e.:

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
       <!-- HERE HAVE SOME LINK TO THE BODY OF test.rb -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file test.html should have extention '**html.erb**'

**test.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
       <%= @body %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In **test.rb** file you should declare instance variable, in this way:

```
@body += '</div></body></html>'
```

Comment: That works. Just to say in case of using Ruby and not Ruby on Rails, the ERB gem is needed. Good to know, thanks.